# NVMeOF/RDMA sync file modifications

Tags: caching, operating-system, solid-state-drive, rdma, nvme

I just set up the NVMeOF/RDMA environment to play around. I have a target node which NVMe SSD is accessed by some client nodes. However, when I delete a file say `test` on one client node, the rest nodes cannot see this operation and can still read the content of `test` as normal. I know that RDMA bypasses the kernel, so I guess this is because of the cache? I then have tried to clean up the cache using these commands:
`sudo sync; echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
`sudo sync; echo 1 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
`sudo sync; echo 2 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

Unfortunately, other nodes still keep this file.

So actually I have two questions:

1. Does it exactly due to the cache? How does it work?
2. What is the correct way to clean up the cache so that other nodes can see the deletion without re-mount?

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Relatively short answer**

Like Boris said, you don't want to do that (distributed consistency on storage is a *hard* problem), and you need something else to do what you want. Flushing caches may not work because you've got multiple distinct views of the system + caching behaviors

**Longer answer:**

As Boris mentioned, NVMeoF is a *block* protocol. This means that at a broad level (with some hand-waving) all it can do is read and write blocks at a particular address. In practice, we usually have layers *above* the NVMe/NVMeoF communication layer like file systems that handle this abstraction.

I can't tell right now if you're using a file system or if you reading/writing the device directly, but in either case you are at least partially correct that the page cache may be getting in the way, even with RDMA.

Now, if you are using local file systems on your client nodes, you quickly get inconsistent views. The filesystem (and consequently overall operating system and its view of the state of the page cache and block storage) has no idea anyone else wrote anything. So even if you write and sync on one client, you may have to bypass the page cache on another (e.g. use O_DIRECT reads, which have their own sets of complexities) and make sure you target something that eventually refers to the same *block* addresses that were written on the NVMe target from your other client.

In theory, this will let you read data written by another if everything lines up correctly, in practice though this can cause confusion, especially if a file system or application on one client writes something at a location, and the other client attempts to read or write that location unknowingly. Now you have a consistency problem.

Answer (score 1):

NVMeoF (with RDMA or any other transport) is a block level storage protocol and not a file level storage protocol. Thus, there is no guarantee to the atomicity of file operations across nodes in NVMeoF systems. Even if one node deletes a file, there is no guarantee that:

1. The delete operation was actually translated to block erase operations and sent to the storage server;
2. Even if the storage server deleted the blocks, there is no guarantee that other clients that have cached this data will not continue to read it. Moreover, another client can overwrite the deleted file.

Overall, I think that to have any guarantees at the file level, you should consider a distribute file systems, rather than NVMeoF.

> What is the correct way to clean up the cache so that other nodes can see the deletion without re-mount?

There is no good way to do it. Flushing the cache on all nodes and only then reading may work, but it depends on the file system.